# Execute popads or popups for only PC visitors

Tags: javascript, php, css, popup

I am using wordpress cms. I am only using pop up ads. I want to execute the pop up ads code for only PC visitors. Can you plz convert my code for it. And plz tell me the procedure to do it. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _pop = _pop || [];
  _pop.push(['siteId', ###]);
  _pop.push(['minBid', 0]);
  _pop.push(['popundersPerIP', 0]);
  _pop.push(['delayBetween', 0]);
  _pop.push(['default', false]);
  _pop.push(['defaultPerDay', 0]);
  _pop.push(['topmostLayer', false]);
  (function() {
    var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    pa.src = '//c1.popads.net/pop.js';
    pa.onerror = function() {
      var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
      sa.src = '//c2.popads.net/pop.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
    };
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I just want to run this code for only PC visitors.

Comment: why is this tagged with PHP ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if user is currently using a mobile browser. There are many ways to achieve that, one of them is quoted from [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/1399505)

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

Next, insert this

```
if (window.mobilecheck()) {return;}
```

before the line

```
var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with jquery : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/
should be easy